# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, exception

I got "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" Exception when I want to use a certain jar file.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: .
org/apache/http/client/ClientProtocolException
    at ?uk.org.taverna.server.client.connection.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:63)
    at uk.org.taverna.server.client.Server.<init>(Server.java:99)
    at uk.org.taverna.server.client.Server.<init>(Server.java:126)
    at uk.org.taverna.server.client.Server.connect(Server.java:293)
    at uk.org.taverna.server.usage.ServerUsage.Usage(ServerUsage.java:24)
    at Test.main(Test.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
```

I import this jar file to jar library, when I call the method in that jar file I got this Exception. By the way, This jar file be wrote by myself, and I can run it correctly.
I have no idea how to solve this problem, I am quite new in java.

Thanks in advance.

Sandy

Comment: It can find org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException.  This is likely due to a missing jar file, as suggested by Rafael.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need also at least HttpClient jar-library. You can get it at [Apache Commons](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) web-site.

Jar libraries may and often refer to another jar libraries. In your case library you are using refers to HttpClient library from Apache Commons framework. You need to add this library to your project.

Comment: The answer is definitely correct but I wonder why is the HttpClient not added as transitive dependency for fluent-hc when used via maven?

Comment: @Jan I think it would be better to address this question [to the team](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/team-list.html), developed this library.

Comment: I found out the product is ok. Just experienced some weird behaviour when trying to import `fluent-hc` in version 4.4.1. Then googled this shouldn't even exist probably. I went with `4.3.6` and that has all the transitive dependencies set as expected. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You should but all the jar files you use in you application in the `libs` folder in your application directory .
so if you use the `apachecommons` jar file copy and paste the jar file to the `libs` folder in your application .