# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException while running Breiman example in Mahout

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I am trying to run Breiman example of building decision forest for classification in Mahout on a single system (pseudo distributed mode). I am referring [this tutorial](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/breiman-example.html)
   I have no problem with the first two steps of the tutorial but the third step (which is 'Generate a file descriptor for the dataset') is throwing exception as shown below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.tools.Describe
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:149)
```

The command I ran is

```
hadoop_admin@ubuntu:~/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar /home/viggi/workspace/mahout-distribution-0.5/mahout-core-0.5-job.jar org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.tools.Describe -p data10/glass.data -f data10/glass.info -d I 9 N L
```

I found a post in stack overflow with similar exception. [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377099/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror) Even though its not related to mahout or Breiman example I decided to go with the recommended solution which is to download `HttpClient jar-library` and put it in `$MAHOUT_HOME/lib`. It didn't work. So if someone could explain what that 3rd step actually does and how to get rid of those exceptions,it would be really helpful.

Comment: In a console, can you execute the following: `jar -tvf mahout-core-0.5-job.jar | grep Describe` - and confirm that the class is listed in the output

Comment: @ChrisWhite Describe.class is present in that jar. Here's the output -- 6995 Sat May 28 14:07:08 IST 2011 org/apache/mahout/df/tools/Describe.class

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, Mahout 0.5 doesn't have the `org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.tools.Describe` class, which is why you are getting the exception, it cannot find it.

From Mahout 0.6 the class is there. I suggest you upgrade to the latest stable version of Mahout (0.7)

Comment: But Mahout 0.5 has org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.tools.Describe class

Comment: I just double checked. You are right, 0.5 does include the `Describe` class, but in the `org.apache.mahout.df.tools`. Note that it does NOT have the `classifier` package in its path. From Mahout 0.6 and on it seems they moved the `df` package into the `classifier` package. So, using `org.apache.mahout.df.tools.Describe` as the command line argument should do the trick.

Comment: It worked!!! You are right, 'Describe' class was never inside 'classifier' package. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your package for `Describe` appears to be wrong - in the 0.5 core-job.jar i just downloaded, the package for Describe did not include the classifier portion:

- `org.apache.mahout.df.tools.Describe`

Not sure how you got this to compile in your code though